# Sending request after timeout of inactivity

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to write a code that behaves like google's translate form.

When I enter a letter in the input text-box, there is a `0.5` second delay that waits for new input. If no new input is received, the request is sent to the server which will return the results on an output text-box.

I wrote something, but it is not complete. Could you help me?!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#source').keyup(function(){
    var keyUpTime = $.now();
    setTimeout(function(){
      if($.now() - keyUpTime >= 500) {
        sendValue($('#source').val());
      }         
    },500);         
  });
});

function sendValue(str){
  $.post("ajax.php",{ sendValue: str }, function(data){
    $('#result_box').html(data.returnValue);
  }, "json");
};
```

Comment: Each keyup needs to cancel the old timer and start a new one. Then you don't need to compare with `keyUpTime` -- if the timer hasn't been cancelled, it must be past the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wonted:

```
var keyUpTime = 0;                  
    var t = 0;
    var executeAfterOneSecond = false;
    $('#source').keyup(function(){
        if(executeAfterOneSecond == false){
            executeAfterOneSecond = true;
            t = setTimeout(function(){
                executeAfterOneSecond = false;
                sendValue($('#source').val());                          
                }, 600);
            }                                   
        keyUpTime = $.now();
        setTimeout(function(){
            if($.now() - keyUpTime >= 200) {
                clearTimeout(t);
                executeAfterOneSecond = false;
                sendValue($('#source').val());          
                }           
            },200);
    });
```

If the interval between letters is less than 200ms, the request is not sent. If passed 600ms, and the request has not been sent, then request is automatically forwarded. If the interval between letters is more than 200ms, request is send.

Answer (score 0):

Store your timeout so it can be overridden in the event of a new event, but sent off if nothing further was supplied. Simply stated:

```
var ajaxTimeout = null;
$('#source').on('keyup', function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (ajaxTimeout){
    clearTimeout(ajaxTimeout);
  }
  ajaxTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    sendValue(val);
  }, 0.5e3); // 0.5 seconds
});
```

Comment: Well, this is not working for me. Doing the same thing like my code. In my code var keyUpTime should be global. I found the solution for my problem.

Comment: Oops, forgot you need to `clearTimeout` first. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aZrgN/).